# Flexbox: Negative margin, why does this work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I was playing around with a layout and I kind of stumbled across a cool trick, but I don't know why it works? Link to example.

http://codepen.io/TaylorHuston/pen/NNjZqZ

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <button id="expand">Expand</button>
  </div>
</div>

.....

body {
  background-color: green;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  width: 1300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto; 
}

#left {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

#left.expanded {
  width: 300px;
}

#right {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  margin-right: -400px;
}

....

$('#expand').click(function() {
  $('#left').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

With that code, when you click on the 'expand' button, the left column expands out to 300px wide, and the right column is pushed over 300px. And it is actually pushed over, it doesn't just shrink to accordingly. If no negative margin is set though, nothing happens, since #right is 100% width. Why does a negative margin allow the #right to be pushed when there is something to the left of it, but doesn't actually move or affect it when there isn't?

Comment: Nothing happens even if you remove `display: flex;` which is also important in this specific case.

Comment: The demo, still, horizontal scrollbar appears when the left is expanded.

Comment: In the demo there's also another issue, and that's the `<button>` tag being closed with `</div>`. Quite silly.

Comment: The margin seems to facilitate the width of `expanded`. By that i mean if you set the margin to something like `-200px` it will only expand to 200. Interested to see more info on this.